# PHP remote ssh script get stderr and determine when script execution is over

Tags: php, ssh

I am execute a remote script using PHP.
I redirect the ouput of the script to a file so i can get the output.
But i want to know when the script has finished so i can be able to show the complete output.

```
public function actionLauncher()
{
    $connection = ssh2_connect('server', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'test', 'test');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '. /home/test/counter.sh > out2.txt 2>&1 &');

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);

    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit'); 
    unset($connection);
}

public function actionView()
{
    $connection = ssh2_connect('server', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'test', 'test');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'cat   /home/test/out2.txt');

    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    $processStatus = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
    echo $processStatus;

    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'exit'); 
    unset($connection);

}
```

I want to determine when the counter.sh has finished and the exit status so i can call the actionView() method to show the output.

Comment: Either run it properly asynchronously or run it using blocking, at leaset on the remote system. Stop trying to have your cacke and eat it. If you wan't to find out what the command is doing then 1) don't redirect its output to a file 2) run it in the foreground, not the background. If you want to find uot when the command you ran has finished without closing the connection, then run a command whose output you can recognise in the same ssh2_exec()

Comment: Yes but it’s a long script . So if a run it in foreground it will take to much time

Comment: Some scripts can take like 3 min

Comment: So run it asynchronously - i.e. not in your ssh session.

Comment: But the point of this is to run it on the remote server

Comment: Yes, you are missing the point.

Comment: I ´m sorry but i dont understand